# Visual Studio 2010 Report Designer - Can I automatically set page width/height?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, ssrs-2012

I want the reports that I am designing (I am using SQL Server 2012) to be Landscape and identical in this regard (same page orientation, margins etc.).

Is there a way to set this automatically and to ensure that these constraints are not ignored in the Design pane (or that at least there is a greyed-out area within said pane as a visual cue?).

M

Answer (score 0):

No.  You can set the height and width of each report in the properties, but you will not get a visual cue in the design pane and there is no way to get one.